# How to publish and connect to my own WCF endpoint without Admin rights

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF REST API implemented in a C# class library.  Ultimately I would like the service to be able to be hosted in my own process, or as a Windows service, depending on the user's choice.  So it needs to support both inproc and HTTP bindings.

The following works as admin, but not as a regular user (says it doesn't have rights to open up the HTTP port).

What's my next step?  Should I be using a different protocol for in-proc?  So long as I retain the ability to have it cross-machine on the HTTP binding, I'm satisfied.

```
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(SapphireServiceLib.SapphireService), new Uri("http://localhost:8080/") );
        try
        {
            ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(SapphireServiceLib.ISapphireService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
            host.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to start Sapphire Service Host: " + ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        // Next, connect to the endpoint for our own use

        try
        {
            // Set the max msg large, otherwise max size would be 64K and we couldn't fetch all the logs.
            // REVIEW I suppose this might expose it to a Denial of Service attack if public

            var binding = new WebHttpBinding() { MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue };

            ChannelFactory<ISapphireService> cf = new ChannelFactory<ISapphireService>(binding, "http://localhost:8080");
            cf.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
            SapphireService = cf.CreateChannel();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to service endpoint: " + ex.Message);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: From where are you connecting to the server? Same machine, same network or internet?

Comment: Could be same process, could be Internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the http binding you have to use the `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+80/YourService` command to allow a process without admin rights to use it.

Another option is to switch to netTcpBinding for instance.